# How can I change this GPU code in CPU code?

Tags: model, gpu, cpu, pytorch

All.

This is my simple GPU code in PyTorch.

How can I change this in CPU code?

```
filename=r’./test/bees/1.jpg’
img = skimage.io.imread(filename)

x = V(centre_crop(img).unsqueeze(0), volatile=True).cuda()

model = models.dict(’resnet18’)
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()

model = torch.load(‘model5.pth’)

logit = model(x)
print(logit)
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Thanks, Koalo. But It doesn't  work. I've already done.

Comment: Error happened: 
---> 27 model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
---> 47             output_device = device_ids[0]

Comment: try to remove `model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()` and all the other `.cuda()`

Comment: model = model.cpu() thats all

Answer (score 0):

Enter this code before you call `.cuda()` method

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

and replacing every `.cuda()` with `.to(device)`
Great answer from [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1668)